# Does my facebook app need to approved for public use, IF i'm only using it via access token, api key, and secret

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently using flowflow lite wp plugin to get a feed from my facebook app via page access token, api key, and app secret.  Do I have to get the app reviewed for public use in order to do that or can the app not go through facebook review/approval and fine in developer mode?

Comment: why not just try in developer mode, without review? you don´t even need to develop something for a test, just use the graph api explorer to see what you get.

Comment: @luschn i have been in developer mode and can't get access to the stream on my facebook app.  And yes, teh graph explorer i do get respones(data).

Comment: what stream are you talking about exactly? this is quite broad, you really need to add a LOT more details to your question. (api calls, relevant code, ...)

Comment: @luschn well i'm essentially talking about flowflow lite plugin for wordpress that is trying to get a facebook stream which is on my facebook's app.

Comment: ah, i missed that, my bad. in that case, you should either debug the code of that plugin or ask the creator of the plugin to look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get data of your Page without review by using a Page Token of the Page in question. It is not possible with a simple App Access Token. You may need to provide a Page Token to that plugin somewhere in the settings.

More information about Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Btw, that plugin tells you to use a Page Token too: https://docs.social-streams.com/article/46-authenticate-with-facebook

Comment: right, i mean to say page access token instead of access key.

Comment: And why downvote me?  it's a perfectly legitimate question for this site.

Comment: ...i did not downvote you? did you downvote my answer? it´s definitely correct.

Comment: ...and why did someone else downvote? please explain, i am happy to improve my question if there is something wrong with it. please don´t downvote without a comment, i am here to help ;)